# Encapsulate LINQ GroupBy Select

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking to encapsulate the Select section of the GroupBy to have a more readable, understandable and nicer code. There is anyway to do that?

This is what I have now (And I have a lot of GroupsBy in my code, is not only one, that's another reason to encapsulate as much as possible):

```
 var xTypeAggregatedTransactions = xTypeTrtansactions.
                    .GroupBy(x => new {x.TypeId, x.AccountId})
                    .Select(y => new PayTransactionsCommand
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Narration = item.Name,
                        AccountId = y.Key.AccountId,
                        Credit = y.Sum(z => z.Credit),
                    });
```

This is what I want:

```
var xTypeAggregatedTransactions = xTypeTrtansactions.
                                   .GroupBy(x => new {x.TypeId, x.AccountId})
                                   .AsEnumerable().ToPayTransaction();
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't think it's possible, because of anonymous types you're using to group. You might try doing some reflection based stuff, and create Expression Tree manuall, but don't see it being an easy solution.

Comment: The problem is that `new {x.TypeId, x.AccountId}` is an anonymous type, so you can't pass it to a method that will know what to do with it...

Comment: What is `item` in this?

Comment: Yes, the anonymous type is the problem @ThomasLevesque. Item is another entity I'm getting before of the group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an extension class:

```
public static class TypeTrtansactionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<PayTransactionsCommand> ToPayTransaction(this IQueryable<TypeTrtansaction> query, string itemName)
    {
        return query.GroupBy(x => new { x.TypeId, x.AccountId })
                .Select(y => new PayTransactionsCommand
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Narration = itemName,
                    AccountId = y.Key.AccountId,
                    Credit = y.Sum(z => z.Credit),
                });
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
var xTypeAggregatedTransactions = xTypeTrtansactions.ToPayTransaction(item.Name);
```

Also, you can add more parameters, if you need.

Comment: I thought about this before, but I wanted to know if there it was any other way to do it. Anyway, I'll mark this as the answer because it seems like there is not another solution for that! Thanks

Comment: @TomásEscamez this way is the most common

Comment: I finally went for this option, thanks @Backs. Just a little detail, it's not necessary to use the .AsEnumerable() here, if you are reading, avoid that!

Comment: @TomásEscamez yes, somtimes `AsEnumerable` is needed, if you do complex transormations, that can not be done in sql

Comment: yes of course, sometimes you might need it. But is useless in this example, that's what I was trying to say.